# Adding HTML entity Symbol in a string

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am trying to add ® sign to my string. How do I get it to recognize the @reg; as a symbol in my string?

```
"MyCompany&reg; Official Site"
```

Comment: I am unclear as to the problem.  What does the DOMParser() add to the solution that the direct inclulsion of the "&reg;" into the string did not?

Comment: @jmrker `&reg;` is an HTML entity. JavaScript strings do not automatically decode them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to decode the entity by parsing it as HTML:

```js
const res = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`MyCompany&reg; Official Site`, 'text/html').body.textContent

console.log(res)
```